# How to use dotenv in SvelteKit project?

Tags: dotenv, sveltekit

I'm trying to use dotenv.config() in a SvelteKit project.

I can run `npm run build` successfully. But when I try to start the server (using `node build`), it throws `Error: Dynamic require of "fs" is not supported`.

I tried to comment out the dotenv part in `src/routes/test.js` and build again, and this time the server started without any errors. (I created the project with `npm init svelte@next` without typescript, and except for the codes here, nothing else is changed)

How should I use dotenv here to load environment variables at runtime?

svelte.config.js

```js
import node from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';

const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: node(),
        target: '#svelte'
    }
};

export default config;
```

/src/routes/test.js

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

export function get() {
    return {
        body: {
            test: process.env.TEST
        }
    }
}
```

.env

```
TEST=123
```

Comment: This may help: [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/faq#env-vars)

Comment: I thought "You would need to instantiate dotenv yourself" meant importing dotenv by myself. But I guess the only way now is to prefix the environment variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since a few weeks SvelteKit has a built-in way to handle environment variables:
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-dynamic-private

Answer (score 14):

No need to explicitly load dotenv.
Vite uses dotenv
https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files

You can access your variable via import.meta.env.VITE_MY_VAR

Important is that your env variables must be prefixed with VITE_ in order to get them exposed. And if you are already running npm run dev, quit it and start again.

That worked for me.

Comment: This method works as long as you want those values substituted into your software package at build time.  So, no secrets.  If you want runtime access to database secrets, etc, you'll want to use the solution from @楊斯惟 or similar.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem with env-cmd (https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) by adding `env-cmd`  to the beginning of `svelte-kit dev`, `svelte-kit preview` and `node build`.

Also, use `process.env['TEST']` instead of `process.env.TEST` since process.env.TEST is replaced with ({}) by vite. (https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3176)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

vite has a special config option for server port.

```
// import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import path from 'path';
import dotenv from 'dotenv-flow';

dotenv.config();

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: preprocess(),

    kit: {
        // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
        // target: '#svelte',
        /*
        adapter: adapter({
            // default options are shown
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: 'index.html'
        }),
        */

        adapter: adapter({
            out: './build',
            precompress: true
        }),
        vite: {
            resolve: {
                alias: {
                    $components: path.resolve('./src/components'),
                    $stores: path.resolve('./src/stores'),
                    $api: path.resolve('./src/api')
                }
            },
            build: {
                minify: true
            },
            server: {
                port: process.env.PORT || 3000
            }
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

I have `.env` for defaults (dev etc) and `.env.local` that is ignored in `.gitignore` for production (keys, etc).

When `.env.local` is present it uses that port.

edit: this does not work with `node-adapter` in production. I think we need to declare PORT some other way. it only works with  `npm run dev`