# Is this code hidden for the client in sveltekit?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

Will the api key be hidden from the user?

```
# $lib/config.js

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore/lite";
        
        
const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "my-key",
};
        
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        
export const db = getFirestore(app);


#index.svelte

import {db} from "$lib/config"

db.get...and so on
```

Trying to understand how to deal with things you want to keep hidden in sveltekit as normally js is visible for the user if wanted through source.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use dotenv in SvelteKit project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67964255/how-to-use-dotenv-in-sveltekit-project)

Comment: Everything you want to hide from the user has to be on the server side. You can’t hide API keys if they are used client side.

Comment: @t.niese So how do I do that? Will config.js be visible for the user if I build this and add the app to server?

Comment: I haven't used this firebase sdk before, but you can check your browser's network tab to see if your api key is visible or not.

Comment: @ambiguous58 Yes. I guess it will not be, but I don't understand how as it is js, when seeing this https://youtu.be/OTxIcU_2Qos . Otherwise apiKey is visible for the user.

Comment: You should make the firebase API:s requests on the server side. Your above example will expose the firebase API Key to the clients since it's directly imported in a .svelte file.

Comment: @OskarHane How do I do that? SSR using fetch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to divide your `index.svelte` file into 2 parts. Public and providing data.

BTW: Your code suggestion won't work because the code won't always execute on the server (SSR). You cannot access the database in the browser.

`index.json.js`, always run on server, where you can authenticate user and prepare data. (Read more about [endpoints](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing-endpoints))

```js
import {db} from "$lib/config"

db.get...and so on
```

`index.svelte`, where you load prepared data

```js
<script context="module">
    /** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Load} */
    export async function load({ params, fetch, session, stuff }) {
        const url = `index.json`;
        const res = await fetch(url);

        if (res.ok) {
            return {
                props: {
                    article: await res.json()
                }
            };
        }

        return {
            status: res.status,
            error: new Error(`Could not load ${url}`)
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Best answer. Someone said: "It's normal to have the key on the client like that, all access to resources can be controlled via security rules". Any comment? I like the simplicity of not having to hide the apiKey on the server but want it to be secure. Btw, my code works. It talks to firestore.